# Status of GDAX Sandbox?

Tags: gdax-api

In the gdax-java library there's a note that the sandbox was shutdown.  The GDAX API still mentions it, though, so I tried it and can get lists of orders, make a web socket connection, etc.

However, trying to place an order on the sandbox simply returns {"message":"forbidden"}

Does anyone know the current status of the sandbox? Should I be able to place orders on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDAX Sandbox appears to be up.

Submitted order moments ago:

```
def test3():
buy = auth_client.buy(price=10500,size=1,product_id='BTC-USD')
print(buy)
```

Received this output of buy:

> {'type': 'limit', 'stp': 'dc', 'size': '1.00000000', 'filled_size': '0.00000000', 'executed_value': '0.0000000000000000', 'status': 'pending', 'settled': False, 'post_only': False, 'price': '10500.00000000', 'fill_fees': '0.0000000000000000', 'side': 'buy', 'id': 'removed the order id', 'product_id': 'BTC-USD', 'created_at': '2018-03-02T07:36:04.297056Z', 'time_in_force': 'GTC'}

Ensure you are using currency pairing BTC/USD as I did above.  It will work.

Also, make sure your API is allowed to "Trade."  In the past, I had API's built that were only in the view type.  This would forbid you from Trading using the API.

Comment: A 403: Forbidden could also be the incorrect API Key, Secret or Passphrase I suppose.  May want to verify those items.

Comment: Thanks for verifying that!  I checked the permissions of the API key, so that's good.  If the signing is working that should mean the key, secret, and passphrase is correct, right?

Comment: I created a new API key and tried it in both the Python library and my own Java code.  It works in Python but not in my code, so there's some error in my code I'll work on tracking down.  Thanks for the verification that it should work.